# An inequality involving the power of cosine

Tags: real-analysis

My problem is to prove
$$
\left(\cos\frac{m}{2n}\pi\right)^{4n}\ge \left(\cos\frac{m+1}{2n}\pi\right)^{2n-1}
\left(\cos\frac{m-1}{2n}\pi\right)^{2n+1}
$$
holds for any positive integer $n$ and $m = 1, 2, \dots, n-1$.

Comment: Can you provide some context, as for how this inequality arises, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit more general inequality is
\begin{equation*}
    g(h):=g_x(h):=\ln\frac{\cos ^{1+h}(\pi  (x-h)) \cos ^{1-h}(\pi  (x+h))}{\cos ^2(\pi  x) }\le0 \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
for $x\in(0,1/2)$ and $h\in(0,\min(x,1/2-x))$.

Suppose that indeed $x\in(0,1/2)$ and $h\in(0,\min(x,1/2-x))$, so that  $h\in(0,1/4)$.
Note that
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{g''(h)}\pi=f(\pi  (x-h))+f(\pi  (x+h))-\frac\pi2 c,
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    f(u):=2 \tan u-\frac\pi2  \sec ^2u=(\sin 2u-\frac\pi2)\sec ^2u
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    c:=(1+2 h) \sec ^2(\pi  (x-h))+(1-2 h) \sec ^2(\pi  (x+h)).
\end{equation*}
Obviously, $f(u)<0$ for $u\in(0,1/2)$ and $c>0$. So, $g''<0$ and hence the function $g$ is concave. Also, $g(0+)=g'(0+)=0$. So, (1) follows.